How to calculate sharp corners for polygons with rounded corners?
Basically this question, but in reverse: How to calculate rounded corners for a polygon?
I have (at least) a polygon made up of edges which has round corners in it and I would like to completely eliminate all round corners.
First of all, the setup:
I use a vertical scan line that moves left to right to process the polygons, so I can't "look into the future" therefore I don't know if I am in a round corner or not until I have consumed all angled edges that conform to the below criteria between one horizontal edge and one vertical edge (either one is the start of the corner and the other is the end of the round corner).
I have come up with a solution but it's a brute-force solution so I don't feel very good about it and it's probably error prone so I am hesitant to implement it.
Round corners start with either a vertical or a horizontal edge and end with either a horizontal or a vertical edge. In between are many small angled edges that give the illusion of "rounding".
To determine whether or not any specific angled edge is an angled edge used to construct a round corner, I came up with the following criteria:

The edge has to be relatively "short" (since round corners are represented by many tiny straight angled edges, tinnier than the "ordinary" edge)
The edges constituting the corner's slope are strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in the same quadrant (0 - 90, 90-180, 180-270, 270-360)

My idea is that whenever I detect the first angled edge that fits that bill, I remember the previous edge (which is either horizontal or vertical) and then keep consuming angled edges until either one of the angled edges fails the criteria and it's not a rounded corner, or I find another vertical or horizontal edge which closes the rounded corner. I remember that edge as well.
I would then delete all the angled edges consumed between the starting and ending edges from the polygon, and extend the vertical and horizontal edges that started the round corner until they meet at a point. Done
This would straighten the corner, but as I said I don't feel good about this solution and I really feel like it'll be slow given I process huge numbers of edges. Also, importantly, I feel like it's difficult for this solution to not be buggy and maybe suffer from false-positives.
Any ideas?

"I really feel like it'll be slow": have you implemented it? Was is too slow? For which input?

I haven't implemented it, but I know from experience that my input is usually in the "very large" side of things (gigabytes, probably tens maybe hundreds) so I am usually a little bit cautious when approaching ideas that seem "obviously slow" and I like to explore other ideas first before committing to a solution and all that solution entails.

OK, but you surely have to read every point/edge from the input. There is no way around it. All the rest your proposed algorithm does it calculating distances and angles, and sure that is something you need to do anyhow. That's why I asked whether you implemented it. Only then you can know whether it really is too slow.

Yeah that's true. I will be trying my solution later today, maybe tomorrow. I thought I'd ask the question anyways while I do that just to get some perspective either on my own solution or on other solutions I haven't considered.

Can you clarify what the input is?  An image?  A set of vertices and edges?  Something else?

Are there any constraints on the types of polygon? E.g., regular? convex?

Your idea sounds good, actually.  It should take linear time to run over the entire set of polygons as a post-process.
Don't start processing at a "corner candidate" edge, though. Start processing at each "real" horizontal or vertical edge, and check if each end is connected to a deletable round corner.
It sounds like you're using a sweep-line algorithm to constructing polygons from segments.  In that case, every time you add a real horizontal or vertical edge, you can check to see if it's connected to a pre-existing deletable corner.  Every rounded corner will be deleted when its later of its two real edges are added.  This has the benefit of checking each corner only once.
If you run the whole thing as a post-process after all the polygons are found, then you can find all the real edges and then check for rounded corners that curve away from it in a clockwise direction.  That will again check each corner only once.
